# How to change hotkey when pressed using AutoHotKey?

Tags: autohotkey

Basically, I'm looking for a way to, when a key combination is pressed, one set of hotkeys is activated, when that key is pressed again, a different set of hotkeys is activated, and  the script is in the off position when first run.

How do I accomplish this?

For example, right now I want to simulate the `NumLock` key, I could do `SetNumLockState [, On]`, but that's useless on keyboards which have no `NumLock` key in the first place, which is the reason why I want to simulate it.

Answer (score 2):

You can remap the NumLock key like this and F1 will do the toggle and act just like the regular NumLock:

```
F1::NumLock
```

If you want to do toggles manually you can manage a Boolean like this:

```
;initialize
flag := 1

;toggle
flag := !flag
```

Here is a some code that will toggle the whole script on and off:

```
;this will toggle the script on and off and not actually send the Insert key
Insert::Suspend

;this will toggle the script on and off but still send the Enter key
Enter::
  Suspend
  Send {Enter}
Return
```

Comment: I don't understand the last part.

Comment: @AHKFanGuy I added some more stuff to the end after my original answer.  Let me know exactly which part you don't understand, and I will be glad to help.